# select distinct but return other columns using ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to to do a select distinct on the 'url' field while pulling in the data for a few other fields.  I tried the below but it gives me some error message 'missing expression'.  I'm using ORACLE.  Can anyone help me

```
SELECT distinct on url,
                is_aw_grp_id,
                is_aw_page_id,
                eppcm_contentid
  FROM ps_z_google_srch
 WHERE     url <> ' '
       AND EPPCM_CONT_TYPE = 'H'
       AND TO_CHAR (dttm_imported, 'dd-MON-yyyy HH:MM:SS') >=
              (SELECT TO_CHAR (LASTCHANGEDTTM, 'dd-MON-yyyy HH:MM:SS')
                 FROM PS_Z_CONT_LAST_CHG
                WHERE RECNAME = 'Z_GOOGLE_SRCH')
```

Comment: I also tried using 'group by url' but I got an error saying 'not a group by expression'

Comment: If you remove distinct, do you get several rows for one url (or several)? If that's the case, you need to make up rules which values for the other selected columns to chose. (MAX, MIN etc.)

Comment: what exactly are you expecting to see? If you've got the same url across multiple rows, are you expecting to see the url on the first line and then blank for the rest? Or something else? Please update your question with sample input data and the expected output.

Comment: Suppose you have 10 rows with the same url, what do you want to see in the other columns? Which `is_aw_grp_id` do you want, for example?

Comment: i want it to show all distinct urls with the is_aw_grp_id, is_aw_page_id, eppcm_contentid columns

Comment: That isn't any clearer. Suppose you have 3 rows for the same url, each with different is_aw_grp_id, is_aw_page_id and eppcm_contentid values. What would you expect the output to be? Which values should be displayed for the is_aw_grp_id, is_aw_page_id and eppcm_contentid columns?

Answer (score 5):

The 'on' is a keyword and is causing this error to be thrown; it's confusing the parser. It isn't needed or valid for [`distinct` in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#CHDDCHGF) (as I believe it is for PostgreSQL, so maybe other databases too), so remove that word:

```
SELECT distinct url,
                is_aw_grp_id,
                is_aw_page_id,
                eppcm_contentid
...
```

That will get all distinct *combinations* of those four fields. Assuming your URLs appear in multiple rows, if you only want to show each URL once then you'd need to decide which value you want for the other three fields - from all the rows for that URL - which could be done with aggregate or analytic functions, or a subquery, depending on the data and requirements.

---

Off-topic, but this looks odd:

```
TO_CHAR (dttm_imported, 'dd-MON-yyyy HH:MM:SS') >=
              (SELECT TO_CHAR (LASTCHANGEDTTM, 'dd-MON-yyyy HH:MM:SS')
...
```

You're converting two dates to strings, and then comparing them with string semantics; so '01-MAR-2015' would sort before '28-FEB-2015', as 1 comes before 2 in the character set. If you were going to compare as strings they should be in a form where comparison makes sense, like ISO format. But converting them both to strings doesn't make sense anyway, just compare them as dates:

```
dttm_imported >= (SELECT LASTCHANGEDTTM
...
```

You could also join the two tables rather than using a subquery.